# N++ Ceritfication: Find Invalid MAC address

Tags: mac-address

Someone please explain this for me: for N+ certification, I can not use my phone, notes or books (during the test) but I am asked to determine which MAC address is invalid. All are valid to me but I am being told by N+ that C is invalid. How can I tell which are fake and which ones are correct?

```
A.  AA:CE:58:FD:90:08
B.  44:98:3E:F8:33:23
C.  56:AD:BX:89:55:54
D.  94:9E:FE:EE:8C:DF
```

Answer (score 0):

Values in MAC address must be valid hexadecimal numbers. BX is not so C is not a valid MAC.